# Docker Compose hangs on INFO Starting development server for `vue-cli-service serve`

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I'm having an issue where I am attempting to spin up a Vue.js and Flask (and PostgreSQL) environment with Docker. However, I'm seeing the docker-compose verbose output perpetually hang on `vue-cli-service serve "--port" "3000" "--verbose"` > with the out output just being:

```
vue_1       |  INFO  Starting development server...
```

It doesn't get any further...

I'm at a loss as to how to debug this. All I could thinking of initially was that my Docker daemon didn't have enough memory allocated, I've since bumped this up to 8GB, 2CPUs.

I have also tried expose the same port in the Dockerfile: `EXPOSE 3000`

I've added the `YOUR_APP_WEB_HTTP_PORT=3000` to the `environment` of the `vue service` in my docker file.

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./hug-docker/flask/Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r /app/requirements.txt && FLASK_APP=app/main.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80"
    environment:
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    env_file: hug-flask/hug_app/.env
    volumes:
      - ./hug-flask/hug_app:/app
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  vue:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./hug-docker/vue/Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "cd /hug-frontend && npm install && npm run serve -- --port 3000 --verbose"
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - CHOKIDAR_INTERVAL=100
      - YOUR_APP_WEB_HTTP_PORT=3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./hug-frontend:/app
  postgres:
    build:
      context: ./hug-docker/postgres/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=database
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
```

Dockerfile for vue service:

```
FROM node:current-alpine
EXPOSE 3000
ADD ./hug-frontend /hug-frontend
```

I expected the webpack/vue development server to spin up in roughly the same time as it does locally, within reason ... but it just perpetually hangs. I've left it for over an hour but realistically even if it didn't spin up in that time then it wouldn't be ideal.

Here is a screenshot of the rough output:

[image]

Maybe worth noting when restarting Docker I see the following:

[image]

Comment: Did you correctly restart your Docker? I assume you are on Mac OS, this may help https://danielkorn.io/post/restart-docker-mac/

Comment: I've restarted Docker multiple times - added more memory etc. But the run just hangs on starting the development server....

Comment: One way to debug this is to shell into the offending service (`docker exec -it vue_1 bash`) and do a `ps aux` to see what is actually running. I wonder if I would then modify the service temporarily just to run a sleep command (whatever to keep it busy and not exiting) and then run the intended command in the shell.

Comment: Next I would play around with tty/interactive options - it looks like the service is not set up for tty interactivity, and I wonder if that is blocking shell output, which in turn stops the service from fully starting.